# Changing the color when mouse hovers over nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I change the color of the `menu-bar` when mouse hovers over the `menu-item`?[image]

Comment: have you tried `.menu-item:hover` already? You can set it: `.menu-item:hover { background: #000; }`

Answer (score 1):

So, in order to make this 'hover' effect, you should make use of css's `:hover`, allowing you to set styling to an element / class/id when the mouse is hovered over it. And since you are talking about the background color, you can even make it transition nicely:

[read more about `:hover`...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  background:gray;
  transition: all 0.8s; /*allows animation*/
  padding:10px;
  margin:5px;
  }

div:hover{
  background:lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<div>hi. You could hover me</div><div>...or me</div>
```

---

**Note**

This is a generic pattern/way of styling elements. You can edit your css to be styled for hover effects on other **elements;**

```
elementTag:hover{}
```

**classes;**

```
.className:hover{}
```

**id's;**

```
#MyID{}
```

or **'other selectors';**

```
.myParentClass:hover .myChild{}
```

for example, the above selector will change the child element if its parent is hovered.

---

There is also `:active` and `:focus` selectors which define rules when the selection is 'active' or 'focused', but this is more in line with text inputs.

As a side note; these **css2.1's** selectors are available for [a LOT of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) - so much so, even IE 7 supports it! So can be safely used on *all* websites :)

[Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

Comment: Is this the way for bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap is a css library, so yes, it is.

Comment: @Suhail - it is generic (CSS) way of styling the div's, but you can use your classes to adjust it.

Comment: @jbutler - well done - just one note - :hover pseudo selector is not css3 specific, but css2.1 If to believe [this document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)